# How to add a field SearchSources as multiselect kendo ui when you press AddNewRubrica in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, multi-select

My Model:

```
public class Rubrica
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
    [UIHint("SearchSourcesEditor")]
    public IEnumerable<SearchSource> SearchSources { get; set; }
}


public class SearchSource
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show you view and the code you have tried.